# How to calculate the run time of algorithm?

Tags: c++, runtime

I saw this code while I was trying to figure out how to calculate run times. I understand that the two for loops are calculated to `n^2` but the swap part throws me of. I'd like to understand if the swap part has any affect on the worse case scenario run time , would this just be `O(n^2)`?

```
for(i = -1; i < N; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < N-1; j++) {
        if a[j] > a[j + 1] {
            swap( a[j], a[j + 1] )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: depends on what you're counting: comparisons or swaps - they differ in that comparisons are exactly n^2 many, but swaps are dependant on your input array (think of an array that's already sorted -> 0 swaps; maybe you're task is to find an example array for the best/average/worst-case for swap)

Comment: this is all the code that he gave us , no input array. though he did give us some choices . and no this isn't homework lol , this is what we were looking at in a slide , i was stumped with it and want to figure it out in case he gives it on a test. i thought it was choice 2                               1)A * N + B + C  ,
 2)A * N^2 + B * N + C  ,
 3)A* N + B * log N + C  ,
 4)A * N * log N + B * log N + C

Comment: can't speak for your teacher, but as I said: the number of swaps depends on the input array. you don't need to be given said array, imagine them: there's one for best and worst case and there are many for the average case - the number of swaps on those differ (but not the number of comparisons!)

Comment: ok i see what ur saying , so the worst case scenario . i think the witch would occur 1 time , i think lol. im thinking an array with 2 items is worst case right? so they switc once

Comment: there is a general worst case for an array with n objects. try going from 2 to 3, to 4, till you see the pattern :)

Comment: well after goin at it , i got the worst case scenario as O(n^2) which seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the worst case scenario, have a data setup with worst case scenario in mind, then use the time command to measure the real time, time command show time of your program work in terms of elapsed time, CPU time (sys and user)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < N-1; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N-1; ++j) {
        if a[j] > a[j + 1] {
            swap(a[j], a[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

the number of comparisons is constant at (n-1)*(n-1). the number of swaps depends on the input array. the worst case is a reversely sorted array: {n, n-1, n-2, ..., 2, 1} this produces n*(n-1)/2 swaps.

for bubblesort you can halt as soon as the inner loop produced no swap:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N-1; ++i) {
    bool hasSwap = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < N-1; ++j) {
        if a[j] > a[j + 1] {
            swap(a[j], a[j + 1]);
            hasSwap = true;
        }
    }
    if(!hasSwap)
        break;
}
```

now the number of comparisons also depends on the input array.

Answer (score 0):

The worst case computation complexity is O(n^2) as you described, the comparison and swap can be ignored as far as the overall complexity is concerned as the dominant term is O(n^2), the code can be rewritten as follows:

```
for(i = -1; i < N; i++)
  for(j = 0; j < N-1; j++)
    function...
```

You should have a look at the rules for big-O simplification:

- If f(x) is a sum of several terms, the one with the largest growth rate is kept, and all others omitted.
- If f(x) is a product of several factors, any constants (terms in the product that do not depend on x) are omitted.